# Why is $C^{k}([a,b],||\cdot||)_{C^{k}}$ a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

If $\mathbb{K}\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$ and $||\cdot||_{C^{k}}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}||f^{(k)}||_{\infty}$, why is this a complete norm on $C^{k}([a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{K})$?

Comment: It boils down to "uniform convergence preserves continuity" and using the fundamental theorem of calculus to say something about the derivatives.

Comment: could you be more explicit on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give the basic ingredients of the proof in the case $k = 1$ (for higher $k$ simply use induction).

Let $(f_h)_h \subset (C^1([a,b]),||\cdot||_{C^1})$ be Cauchy, i.e.
$$\forall \, \epsilon > 0 \,\, \exists N \,\text{such that} \, h,k > N \, \Rightarrow \, ||f_h - f_k||_{\infty} + ||f_h' - f_k'||_{\infty} < \epsilon$$
Note that in particular $(f_h)_h$ and $(f_h')_h$ are Cauchy in $(C^0([a,b]),||\cdot||_{\infty})$, which is a Banach space,  as a consequence $\exists f,g \in C^0([a,b])$ such that $f_h \to f$ and $f_h' \to g$ uniformly on $[a,b]$.
All you need to prove is that $\exists f'(x) = g(x)$ for every $x \in (a,b)$. This part of the proof requires the uniform convergence of $(f_h')_h$ and the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$f_h(x) = f_h(a) + \int_a^xf_h'(t)dt$$
for every $x \in (a,b)$ and $h \in \mathbb{N}$, which gives
$$f(x) = f(a) + \int_a^xg(t)dt$$
and since $g \in C^0([a,b])$ then $\exists f'(x) = g(x)$ for every $x \in (a,b)$

We have proved that $\exists f \in C^1([a,b])$ such that $||f_h - f||_{C^1} \to 0$ and thus $(C^1([a,b]),||\cdot||_{C^1})$ is a Banach space